# how to list blocked connections events by the firewall?

Tags: shell-script, firewall

So, I used firestarter that had logged blocked connections events with some useful details (but it is not being updated and I found somewhat unsafe as any moment we could click to deactivate the firewall.)

I would like to know if there is some way to do that with a command-line script?
also to translate remote IPs into url names optionally?

or if there is some graphical application that helps on showing that!?

There is conntrack-tools, but how to use it? It seems new kernel versions, new ubuntu releases, that won't work properly. I used to be able to track scanport attacks, now I have no clue.

Comment: There is no translation from IP addresses to URLs. Only hostnames, and not always.